# Difference between filter and group_by when calculating change

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate percentage change but I don't get why this error occurs:

`Column 'change' must be length 1 (the group size), not 0`

Here's an `example` data frame:

```
structure(list(Kennisnamedatum = structure(c(16436, 16436, 16441, 
17167, 17167, 17169), class = "Date"), weekdag = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", 
"Sat", "Sun"), class = "factor"), jaar = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L), Gemeente = c("Amsterdam", "Rotterdam", 
"S-Gravenhage", "Amsterdam", "S-Gravenhage", "Rotterdam"), Plaats = c("Amsterdam", 
"Rotterdam", "S-Gravenhage", "Amsterdam", "S-Gravenhage", "Rotterdam"
), Beleidscode = c("Bezit harddrugs", "Bezit harddrugs", "Bezit harddrugs", 
"Bezit harddrugs", "Bezit harddrugs", "Bezit harddrugs"), aantal_misdrijven = c(16L, 
1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L), misdrijven_per_jaar = c(829L, 368L, 205L, 
649L, 197L, 349L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), vars = c("jaar", "Gemeente", 
"Beleidscode"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("Kennisnamedatum", "weekdag", 
"jaar", "Gemeente", "Plaats", "Beleidscode", "aantal_misdrijven", 
"misdrijven_per_jaar"), indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    jaar = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), Gemeente = c("Amsterdam", 
    "Rotterdam", "S-Gravenhage", "Amsterdam", "Rotterdam", "S-Gravenhage"
    ), Beleidscode = c("Bezit harddrugs", "Bezit harddrugs", 
    "Bezit harddrugs", "Bezit harddrugs", "Bezit harddrugs", 
    "Bezit harddrugs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), vars = c("jaar", "Gemeente", "Beleidscode"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("jaar", 
"Gemeente", "Beleidscode")))
```

When I filter the data frame on cities (`gemeente`), Fellonies (`Beleidscode`) and leave two years (`jaar`) then I want to calculate change it works. But I don't want to filter but calculate across all (df: `wob_df`) `gemeente` per `Beleidscode` and per `jaar`. `group_by` would have been the obvious choice but that doesn't work. I can't wrap my head around this...

Code that works (with original `wob_df`, too big a data frame to share):

```
library(dplyr)

wob_df %>%
  distinct(Gemeente, .keep_all = T) %>%
  filter(Gemeente %in% c("Amsterdam", "Rotterdam", "S-Gravenhage"),
         Beleidscode == "Bezit harddrugs",
         jaar != 2016) %>%
  group_by(Gemeente) %>%
  mutate(change = (misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2017] - misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2015]) / misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2015])
```

Same task but then without filter:

```
wob_df %>%
  group_by(Gemeente, Beleidscode, jaar) %>%
  mutate(change = (misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2017] - misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2015]) / misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2015])
```

This gives the following error:

```
`Column 'change' must be length 1 (the group size), not 0`
```

Comment: It's not the same, because apart from removing the filter you group by 3 variables and not only one. It will work if you use `group_by(Gemeente)` instead of `group_by(Gemeente, Beleidscode, jaar)`. So, when you group by 3 variables you have either a 2015 value or a 2017 value in each group, not both, and you cannot subtract within each group.

Comment: That doesn't work. Because I want to calculate change between the year 2017 and 2015 per `Beleidscode` and `Gemeente`

Comment: It works with the example you posted above.

Comment: Yes, so that's because I made that dataframe smaller for reproducibility purposes.  Maybe see my comment on the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already cleaned your data to have one misdrijven_per_jaar per Gemeente and Beleidscode (so you can do a one-for-one change), reshaping your data makes this so much simpler. This is what tidyr is for. I'll load it via tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
    select(Gemeente, Beleidscode, jaar, misdrijven_per_jaar) %>% 
    group_by(Gemeente, Beleidscode) %>% 
    spread(jaar, misdrijven_per_jaar) %>% 
    mutate(difference = `2017` - `2015`)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Gemeente, Beleidscode [3]
  Gemeente     Beleidscode     `2015` `2017` difference
  <chr>        <chr>            <int>  <int>      <int>
1 Amsterdam    Bezit harddrugs    829    649       -180
2 Rotterdam    Bezit harddrugs    368    349       - 19
3 S-Gravenhage Bezit harddrugs    205    197       -  8
```

You can play tunes as you like to calculate relative change etc.

Comment: You shouldn't actually need the group_by, it's a leftover from me not quite knowing what your column were about.

Comment: Ah maybe spreading it first and then gather again makes sense. Good tip!

Comment: Oh okay, but if you want to keep your original rows, so long as you've calculated differences for each combination of Gemeente and Beleidscode, you can always join with your original data frame on those columns, e.g. mydf %>% "calculate differences as above" %>% join(mydf)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to group by year if you want to put conditions on years ..

```
df %>%
  group_by(Gemeente, Beleidscode) %>%
  mutate(change = (misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2017] - misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2015]) / misdrijven_per_jaar[jaar == 2015])
```

Comment: With the given `example` dataframe, that works but not with my original dataframe which is kind of like the same only than consists of 3 years multiple `Beleidscode` values and way more `Gemeente` values.

Comment: Pehaps you should remoce the groups where there is not data for year 2017 or year 2015, no ?